# How can I scroll through a fixed list and loop it when it finishes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a list of say 4 elements that I want the user to select from

```
final List<String> alphabets = ['a','b','c','d'];
int value = 0;

increaseValue(){
value+=1;
}
```

Then in build I use

```
RaisedButton(child:Text(alphabets[value]),onPressed:increaseValue),
```

Now this will give an error once the index goes above 3. How do I loop the list such that index 4 gives me the first alphabet in the list?

Comment: How about checking if (value +1 > alphabets.length)  then make value 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lib carousel_slider (https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) to create a circular list of widgets or if you don't want use any external libs, you can try adjusting your increaseValue function to something like this:

```
increaseValue(){
  value = value == alphabet.length ? 0 : value++;
}
```